# How to describe a lot of experience in a formal way?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a formal introduction article, I want to describe somebody who has a lot experience on software engineering.

Is there any formal words to replace "a lot"? For example, I have ____ experience on xxx.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The transparent metaphorical usage of **wealth** is often used to express this, though it sounds better not used in a first-person setting:

> Jane has a wealth of experience in handling delicate relational
>   situations.

The loose quantifier 'a wealth of' is given by, for example, [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wealth):

> *wealth* noun (LARGE AMOUNT)
>
> ​ C2 [ S ] a large amount of something good:
>
> *Jim has a wealth of teaching experience.*

It is certainly not out of place in a formal setting.

Answer (score 1):

If it's applicable, then a time reference works well:

> (name) has more than a **decade** of experience...

[source](https://www.publichealthonline.org/pre-professional-experience/)

*Also: (more than) fifteen years of, a lifetime of... etc*

Another option:

> ... we have a **depth** of experience in helping clients...

[source](https://www.abacuslandmark.com/services/funds/)

And another one:

> Top-level managers (such as CEOs) tend to be big-picture strategic thinkers with a **substantial amount** of experience in the industry and/or function they manage.

[source](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-management/chapter/management-levels-and-types/)

Comment: Also, I was a bit puzzled with the preposition "on" in your example. I've only encountered "experience in" and "experience with", but never "on", though I'm not 100% sure it cannot be used like that.

Answer (score 1):

*Abundant*, *considerable* or *extensive* would fit. Depending on the nuance you are looking for you might want *wide-ranging* or *indepth*.

But there are *a lot* of possiblities [This thesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/extensive_experience/synonyms) suggests 169 synonyms including *ample* experience, *long-standing* experience, *significant expertise*. The list goes on!